# Task to fire and forget vs background inifinity task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, semaphore

i'm thinking about these two options.
I dont no if Task.Run() called multiple times per second have a poor performance instead a infinite thread with semaphore

1 - Fire and forget

```
...
Task.Run(async () =>
{ 
    //Do();
});
```

2 - background inifinity task

I simplified the code, but the idea is this, a thread is waiting for a signal to process

Start thread

```
ctor()
{
    _thread = new Thread(WriteLog);
    _thread.Start();
}
```

Enqueue and release semaphore

```
public long AddLog(Log aLog)
{
    _buffer.Enqueue(aLog);

    _sm.Release();
}
```

Process every time _sm was release

```
private void WriteLog()
{    
    while (true)
    {
         try
         {
              // Wait release to write log
              _sm.Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
               
              var xBuffer = _buffer.Dequeue()
              // Do()
          }
          catch
          {
          }
      }
```

Comment: This is extremely suspicious `Task.Run(async () =>` you are offloading an async workload to a thread pool thread, Secondly, why are you writing your own logger? just use one of the bazillion tested working frameworks that take care of everything for you

Comment: The code is old and I don't like it at all.
It's not just abbout logger, the endless threads is used for many things in code.
I just want to replace all endless threads running background for a simple Task.Run() every call. like to send sms, email, and another things where I don't need wait a return

Comment: These two options are not equivalent. The `Thread` with the buffer and the semaphore is running the queued jobs sequentially, while `Task.Run`ing everywhere without coordination will result to some jobs running concurrently. Aren't you concerned about the possible thread-safety issues associated with the concurrent execution of random jobs?

Comment: "Aren't you concerned about the possible thread security issues associated with running random jobs simultaneously?"
No problem about this. When necessery i can use semaphore or similar on critical point on task to prevent. It seems to me that no solution is the best, but I don't have much to do. A lot of threads are created per client currently (like 10 per client), so I question if there would be any gain by changing this to fired and forgot calls to do some jobs, like upload on azure, send email and sms, and another tasks

Comment: The `Task.Run` is very efficient, so I would expect that switching from the single-thread solution to `Task.Run` to be at least as fast, if not faster because of the introduced concurrency.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, initially I was afraid of the efficiency of Task.Run in terms of processing and memory, since it will be called several times. I did a simple foreach calling a Task.Run () => { empty } 10,000,000 times, the cpu was 90%, with a semaphore limiting the number of calls, it was 20%, remembering that I was testing the efficiency of the Task.Run() call and not the method that will be executed. Then I will do more tests.